# How can I have multiple forces act on an entity in Bevy?

Tags: rust, game-development, bevy, entity-component-system, rapier

I'm making a game in rust, in Bevy with Rapier2d physics. I want to apply forces to the entities from different functions (systems).

**How is multiple external forces added to entities?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.